# Creating Node.JS Module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been creating software in NodeJS for years, but I have rarely ever looked into the module side of it, since I've never needed to do that stuff myself.

I have created a test.js file, which is my module, all it contains is this (i've tried this.host, self.host, var host ... nothing is working)

```
var tests = function () {
    this.host = "http://127.0.0.1/";
};

exports = tests;
```

In my server.js I try and use it and I can never get host to actually output

```
var tests = require('./test.js');

console.log(tests);
console.log(tests.host);
```

I always get this output, saying that tests variable has no properties ... which I set in the module.

```
sudo node server.js
{}
undefined
```

Comment: i think , you just need to learn javascript , http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Answer (score 3):

The `host` variable as you defined it in the `tests` function is not accessible through `tests`'s [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

This means that in order to access it, you should be creating a new instance of `tests`, using the `new` operator :

```
var Tests = require('./tests');
var instance = new Tests();
// Now you can access `instance.host`
```

Also, as David said, use `module.exports` to export your function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do `exports = tests`. Either do `exports.tests = tests` or `module.exports = tests`.

Comment: Doing that I get
`[Function]
undefined`. (both lines)

I am not sure what to do from there.

Comment: @Jjj you are returning a `function`.  Either execute the function or return an object instead. `var tests = { host: "http://127.0.0.1/" };`

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(tests());` will work if the you add `return` statement inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to first decide if you want your module to just have properties that can be directly accessed or if you want it to have a constructor function that creates an object when it is called that then has properties or it could even just be a regular function that you call that returns a value.  You have mixed and matched the first two schemes (pieces of each) and thus it does not work.  I will show you both schemes:

Here's the scheme where your module exports a constructor function from which you can create an object (when you new it):

```
// test.js module
var tests = function () {
    this.host = "http://127.0.0.1/";
};

module.exports = tests;


// main module server.js
var Tests = require('./test.js');

var t = new Tests();
console.log(t.host);
```

And, here's the scheme where you just directly export properties:

```
// test.js module
module.exports = {
    host: "http://127.0.0.1/"
};


// main module server.js
var tests = require('./test.js');

console.log(tests);
console.log(tests.host);
```

Keep in mind that whatever you assign to `module.exports` is what `require()` will return after it loads your module.  So, in your first case, you're assigning a function that is intended to be a constructor function so you have to use it as a constructor function in order for it to work properly.

In my second example, I assign an object to `module.exports` so you can then treat it just like an object after loading the module with `require()`.  That means you can then just directly access its properties as you would for an object.